# Onelogin php saml toolkit - debugging

Tags: php, saml-2.0, onelogin

M question is it possible to check a generated Authrequest ( before it is signed ) as a test ? either via command line or a php page.

Any advice is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Review the [php-saml toolkit](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml)

If you initialize the [OneLogin_Saml2_AuthnRequest](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml/blob/master/lib/Saml2/AuthnRequest.php#L36) object, later with the [getXML](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml/blob/master/lib/Saml2/AuthnRequest.php#L174) method you will obtain the AuthNRequest XML.

but I recommend you to play with that [demo1](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml/tree/master/demo1) documented [here](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml#demo1) to really underestand the SAML protocol.

You will need to connect your Service Provider with an Identity Provider, if you don't have one, get a [Onelogin trial account](https://www.onelogin.com/signup) and follow the steps described [here](https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/php)

Comment: Thanks! Yep that's the demo I'm testing from will give that a go.